# I'm getting an error once importing JavaFX in eclipse on Mac specifically with one import which is 'org.controlsfx.control.Noticifactions'

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, javafx, controlsfx

I'm getting an error once importing JavaFX in eclipse on Mac specifically with one import which is 'org.controlsfx.control.Noticifactions' what I've tried is to add and delete and re add the javafx sdk it is currently sitting under module path in configure build path and I've also tried to add it to the Class path which causes more errors

module-info.java is where the error is the code is

```
module loanBidda {
requires org.controlsfx.control.Notifications;
requires java.desktop;
requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.graphics;
 }
```

the specific error is 'org.controlsfx.control.Notifications cannot be resolved to a module'

Tried re-installing both SDK's, updated java, updated eclipse, refreshed and cleaned project tried starting a new project with a fresh install, both versions of the javafx and JRE are the same

Default VM arguments are as follows: --module-path /Applications/javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml Main.java

Comment: `requires` expects a module name, not a class name.

Comment: Also `Noticifactions` is not even a correct class name.

Comment: Note if your code is modular then you do not need `--add-modules`. Just make sure your code is launched as a module (i.e., via `--module`).

Comment: I'm effectively just trying to get access to the controlsfx library which does not contain a jar file to add in eclipse so I've added the dependancy to my pom.xml file which is still not working.    Notifications class is just part of the controlsfx library I feel like there is something simple I'm missing here

Comment: As noted, `requires` expects the module name, which is `org.controlsfx.controls`. Also note that if you're trying to use ControlsFX with JavaFX 9+, and assuming you keep JavaFX on the module-path as recommended, then check out [Using ControlsFX with JDK 9 and above](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/wiki/Using-ControlsFX-with-JDK-9-and-above). And finally, if you're using Maven as indicated by your comment, then you should not be downloading JARs manually; just add [the Maven coordinates for ControlsFX](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx/11.1.2) to your POM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a site which packages the controlsfx package into a Jar file which worked

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.controlsfx/controlsfx/11.1.0/source-code